# How to navigate to a specific fragment from all other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

When i press back button from my Home_Fragment the control will go to a empty page ,i want to exit my application when i press back button from Home_Fragment,at the same time when i press back button from all other fragment i want to navigate to Home_Fragment. My MainActivity page is below.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just override the onBackButtnPressed method in each of your fragment

Comment: Remove this line
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: when i press back button the app will exit from all other fragment also if i remove fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write code for onBackButton to check for count of `BackStackEntry`. if atleast one fragement is in it, Count will be more than 0.
 if `count==0` then do `finish()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
           //no fragments left
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: oh sorry its 1. when i think of numbers now. i always start them with 0. programmers. Lol

Comment: the remaining issue is, when i press back button from all other fragment i want to navigate to Home_Fragment, now its go to the previous fragment i selected before the current fragment..

Comment: you got to read google documentation for same http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It works:

Create a method in main Activity to call fragment:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragmentName){
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragmentName);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And call this method by any fragment by the following lines of code:-

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).replaceFragment(FragmentName.class)
```